# Transactional method not write updates on database

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, sql-update, entitymanager

I'm working on a Spring application that uses Hibernate 4.3 to manage data stored in a MySql database.

I want to simply update the value of this object:

```
@Table(name = "CONTENT")
public class KcContent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @DocumentId
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="PRIORITY")
    private Long priority;

    // getter and setter
}
```

This is the point where I update the object:

```
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
public String checkAndManageActionsNewsletter(NewsletterActionRequestBean requestBean) {
    List<String> newsIds = requestBean.getNewsIds();

    // update priority based on position in list
    for(long priority = 0; priority < newsIds.size(); priority++) {
        String newsId = newsIds.get((int) priority);
        long contentId = Long.parseLong(newsId);
        KcContent news = getServiceCatalog().getContentService().find(contentId);
        news.setPriority(priority);
    }
}
```

Where `@Transactional` is imported from `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`.

This code results in **no update on database**. I also tried to add after `setPriority()`:

1. `this.entityManager.merge(news)`
2. `this.entityManager.persist(news)`

but it doesn't work.

I checked the reference to the object in the entityManager after the `setPriority()` method, and the value it's updated.

[image: debug shell check]

In the database instead the value is still the old value (0):

[image]

In the end, I tried to change values on database for the priority, and the application read them correctly, so the problem seems to be only on update.

There is some mistakes in the configuration?

Note: unfortunately I can't use `JpaRepository`.

---

**Update**:
This is the implementation of the `find()` method in the `ContentService` class:

```
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public KcContent find(Long id) {
    if (id == null){
        return null;
    }
    return getEntityManager().find(KcContent.class, id);
}
```

Comment: Why the chained getters? You should be just injecting the `ContentService` into your bean (you shouldn't know about the internals). Also what does the `find` method do? Please add it.

Comment: The chained getters are there because the code was done by people who doesn't know Spring.... Unfortunately I can't inject field right now (due to lack of time, the project is huge). I added the implementation of find method.

Comment: And the `getEntityManager`? Also why not? Adding a single field to this class isn't that much work, you don't have to change the whole code base? Also why this `find` ifyou have the `entitymanager` in your code (but which you apparently aren't using).

Comment: I don't use directly the `find()` method because is already provided in the service. The point here is that the update isn't done, and the `entityManager` is set correctly. Do you think that this can be a problem, apart from the better design? In that case, how can this influence?

Comment: One thing is that the `find` is `readOnly`, which might influence the transactionality. Next to that is the `getEntityManager` returning the same entity manager or creating one? Also how is the initial method being called?

Comment: I tried to remove the `readOnly` flad from the `find`, but it doesn't work either. I added the getter and setter of `entityManager`.

Comment: Then there must be either something wrong in your setup of the entitymanager (wrong context for binding in Spring), your config for the tx manager or the calling method also defines a transaction as read-only. Spring should auto commit, it doesn't so either the tx is readonly or spring isn't actually controlling the entitymanager.

Comment: How can I check if the external transaction is readonly? I mean, is there a way to check it programmatically? What do you mean with *Spring isn't actually controlling the entityManager*?

Comment: That there are multiple entity managers (or transactions). That there is no entitymanagerfactory defined for spring to use or the wrong context to use for the manager (thread instead of spring). How is the method `checkAndManageActionsNewsletter` getting called, that way you know what happens.